Communication between an nrf24l01 and Python program on laptop
I have this project that my lecturer asked me to do. I have an Arduino connected to a number of sensors, and to a nrf24l01 module. I have to transmit this sensor data to my Python program in my LAPTOP via the nrf24lo1, where it will perform some machine learning. However, I have no idea how to make my Python program on my laptop receive this transmitted data.
I thought of using a hackone rtlsdr dongle, which can communicate at 2.4 GHz, but I just learned that they do not speak the same protocol.
